# Generating ID locally to avoid auto creation by mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way to generate an ID for a new document?

Something like

```
var newID = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();

// some random code that may involve db operations.

db.Model.create({_id: newID, otherProperties: {}})
```

When I write something like this, actual ID of the created document is always slightly larger than the newID. Is there anyway to use the newID exactly?

Comment: This code works fine when I try the same approach. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: At least use your own ID field

Answer (score 0):

You should not create ID attribute for mongodb documents, It will automatically generate an ID attribute to all documents when we create them.

e.x

```
db.users.insert({name:'kasun',email:'kasun@gmail',address:'2street,colombo'})
```

this will crete an attribute called **_id** for the document of kasun.It is unique.Therefore don't set id attribute manually.

Comment: `db.Model.create({ otherProperties: {}}) `skip define _id:, all documents automatically added an _id by default

Comment: for y? it is useless

Comment: I need to create some other documents along with the creation of a particular document. I don't want to do a create and then do another update. But that's what i ended up doing. =(